# property of non-object to change value to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a curious question that's going on my mind while looking at my datatables.
I noticed that some columns of my table has no values, like just the column only.
Is it possible when you want to call that column it will return a value of **0**? 
I tried to call it with a simple SELECT query in sql but its giving me a notice.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object MySQL result on line (number line)
```

Can this be used with an if-else statement from the query or a case statement from the query? Hoping for your opinions on this. Thank you :)

Comment: You didn't include any code and you're actually getting an error, even if it does say notice - it's an error, you're not checking the result that you get whether it's successful or not (in your case - it isn't). So, your question can't be answered since you provided 0 code. Can something be used with an if else statement in general programming? By all means! Now, I've no clue how this statement of mine will help you but it appears that the answer you're after is - **yes**.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion :) I'll try to do my code and let you know if I'll encounter an error.

Comment: The notice you posted looks very much like a PHP Notice. Post the code. Both the SQL query and the PHP code that runs it and uses result. I suspect either the SQL query is incorrect and the MySQL library returns `FALSE` or you use a function that returns a row as a PHP array (which, of course, is not an object).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some function like NVL() in Oracle, or IFNULL() in MySQL. This functions set a value when you got a NULL value.